# Does eslint automatically exclude node_modules/?

Tags: eslint

I don't have an .eslintignore file and .eslintrc has no ignore patterns. When I run the following: `./node_modules/.bin/eslint **/*.js`, it appears that files in the node_modules folder are ignored.

The ESLint [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/command-line-interface) makes no mention of any default excluded folders or files. What is the real situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

node_modules is ignored by default

It is in the doc: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/

relevant part:

> In addition to any patterns in the .eslintignore file, ESLint always
> follows a couple of implicit ignore rules even if the --no-ignore flag
> is passed. The implicit rules are as follows:
>
> - node_modules/ is ignored.
> - dot-files (except for .eslintrc.*), as well    as dot-folders and their contents, are ignored.